# pygsl in debian

Tags: debian, package, pygsl

Is it possible to install pygsl in Debian?  I am using the package and someone with Debian is not sure how to install it without ruining his packaging (since it's not in apt-get.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to do a local install. /usr/local is the usual place to put it in.

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py -n install --prefix=/usr/local
```

This ended with an error

error: file '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pygsl/matrix_pierre.py' does not exist

but maybe you'll be able to figure it out. Tested on Debian squeeze.

IMPORTANT: run this as user, not root. That way it can't install to your system directory if the install is screwed up.

The library should install in usr/local/lib/python2.6/ (or whatever your default python version is).

Regards.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll forward it to him.

Comment: when you run this as a user, you cannot provide --prefix=/usr/local, because non-root cannot write there.

Comment: @andreash: You can if you are a member of the staff group. An alternative is to install in the home directory, but I think /usr/local is preferable.